# Did Kylo Ren's plan work too well?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

When Snoke is monologing about

> Kylo Ren's inner emotional gears, all the while about to meet his doom,

and Kylo Ren is

> turning the idle lightsaber on his master

it appears that when it is

> activated, it goes through roughly the middle of Snoke's midsection, then pulled straight forward by Kylo Ren.

Wouldn't the lightsaber have

> only cut through the front half of Snoke?

Yet we later see that the

> cut was clear through.

Did Kylo Ren

> move the saber backwards slightly before bringing it forward?

Comment: The blade appears to have gone through his Snoke's back rather than his middle. It then came forward and cut him in half; https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwdXw.png

Comment: I had the same question while seeing the movie

Comment: I'm going to turn this into a maths question when I get back to work - the angles of lightsabre blades and rotation.

Comment: If Snoke is a vertebrate his spinal column is probably one of the best spots for fatal thrust with a lightsaber, especially if Kylo Ren like we doesn't know anything about the composition of his intestines. - Another possibility could be that Snokes body was so frail that it just broke off after half of his body was cut, maybe he needed the force just to stay in one piece and after his dead the body just crumbled at strained spots.

Comment: @Falco I have kind of been thinking the same thing lately about Snoke's frailty. We never see him stand or walk and given the state of his face he was either in some near death situation or hit every branch falling out of the ugly tree...

Answer (score 2):

It does appear that the lightsaber goes through Snoke's midsection. It's only shown in a single shot, but from the lightsaber's position on the armrest and the visibility of the blade on the left, it doesn't look like it's substantially behind him:

[image: Still frame of lightsaber impaling Snoke]

<sub>([*The Last Jedi* via YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IR9NexyrcM))</sub>

Then, in the next shot, the lightsaber's only apparent movement is to fly towards Kylo Ren and Rey, which is somehow enough to cut Snoke in half:

[image: Animated GIF of Kylo pulling the lightsaber towards Rey, through Snoke]

The novelization doesn't shed much light on this:

> Kylo had indeed rotated the hilt of his lightsaber so it was pointed directly at Rey's chest. But even as he did so, Luke's lightsaber was rotating silently on the armrest of Snoke's throne—unnoticed by either the Supreme Leader or the Praetorian guards.
>
> When Kylo's fingers twitched behind his back, the blue energy blade of Luke's lightsaber sprang into existence, spearing Snoke. Then, with a flick of Kylo's hand, the blade carved through his master, cutting him in two, and flew through the air into Rey's hand as Kylo's ignited his own lightsaber.
>
> <sub>[*The Last Jedi: Expanded Edition*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition), page 292 of Kindle edition</sub>

In short, there's no official confirmation that this is anything other than a slight continuity error or dramatic embellishment.

However, the one other time in the Star Wars films that a lightsaber is kept within an object for an extended period of time, its damage starts spreading outside of the beam's radius. Maybe something similar happened here?

[image: Animated GIF of Qui-Gon stabbing his lightsaber into a metal blast door]

<sub>([*The Phantom Menace* via YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RCYs0N5Wsc))</sub>

Comment: No help in the graphic novelisation; https://i.stack.imgur.com/j82hy.png

Comment: It's also not clear how Kylo ren avoided cutting Snoke's hands off as it moved through his body

Comment: @Valorum Actually, I think he did.  In the gif above before the saber starts to move you can clearly see Snoke's left hand resting on the chair armrest.  As his torso and head fall, you can see that pale gray hand stay put.  I think also his other hand stays where it is.  Clean cut through midsection and wrist/arm.

Comment: @milo-p Just noticed what comes from both Snoke's torso and waist as the torso falls.  It looks to me like sparks.  We don't see that from most things in the films unless they're made of metal.  Given the condition of his face, this now makes me think he may have been "more machine than man now", Vader/Grevious-style.  That could help explain the cut, if it only needed to be far enough back to handle the main supporting internal structure, which needn't have been where a regular spine would typically be.

Comment: Ironically, if Snoke was all machine where the saber cut through, he likely died from a concussive head wound after falling off the chair rather than from the saber cut itself (unless it also severed some bit of life-support line or mechanism that was in that part of the torso).

Comment: @jinglesthula The sparks could also be flying embers from his insides being incinerated, which would fit with the "energy spreading out from the beam" theory.

Comment: That could be too.  Which could even explain the separation.  If the blade didn't initially sever the spine, but did release enough energy to sufficiently weaken the bone and/or connective tissue, that could explain a full separation instead of just a cauterization-closed cut, as many saber swipes look to be in the films.